# Open source alternatives to Amazon RDS for the data center?

Tags: high-availability, amazon-rds

I'm looking to for a technology that is similar to Amazon RDS, where the engine (ie: WS management, setting up, operating, HA, backups, point in time recovery, scale, etc.) can be deployed in your own data center.

Does anything like this exist?

Comment: This is 11 year old question, still there is no alternative for Amazon RDS?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that exists.   I wouldn't know if its possible either, given that I don't know how the RDS nodes are configured for Amazone.    If I were you, I would email the only publicly available person that might know: Jeff at his [blog](http://aws.typepad.com/)  and ask him.